# How to use patch or delete method with link_to via AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a link in a helper via:

```
  def project_archive_link(project)
    if project.archived?
      txt = t :unarchive
    else
      txt = t :archive
    end

    link_to(txt, archive_project_path(project), method: :patch, class: 'tablet_button')
  end
```

I'm then adding it to the page via a js.coffee file (ajax).  But the link, when clicked, always is submitted via GET, not PATCH.

Inspecting the source, I can see the `data-method="patch"` attribute for the link.

Update: It appears this is also true for delete links that are added to the page via ajax.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all custom JS except jQuery in your application.js (restart your webserver in RAILS_ENV=development) and test if the PATCH request still fails.